# Валидация произвольного поля

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Вопрос к знатокам Wordpress и PHP. 
У меня есть Регистрация на сайте, и там добавлено произвольное поле номер телефона. Мне надо, чтобы при регистрации пользователь не мог водить уже используемый номер телефона подобно проверке при воде логина. 
Пользовательское поле "mobile" и, соответственно, в базе запись my_mobile
Я понимаю, что эта валидация реализуется через этот код:

```
if ($_POST['mobile'] == 'здесь какое то условие '){
    $errors->add( 'empty_mobile', "Укажите номер" );
}
```

Также я понимаю, что надо как-то пробежаться циклом по базе в WP и потом подставить в верхние условие, но как это правильно сделать, я не могу сообразить.
Помогите, пожалуйста, начинающему Вордпресовцу.

Answer (score 1):

Надо добавить хук на действие "регистрация".
Суть хука:
 1. Получаем все номера из базы.
 2. Сравниваем введенный адрес с имеющимися в базе.
 3. Продолжаем регистрацию или выдаем ошибку.

В идеале надо делать проверку в реальном времени на JQuery и выдавать информацию сразу, но в этом методе есть большая проблема, потому как можно узнать номера всех зарегистрированных пользователей.

Comment: А можете показать кодом на моем примере, если вам не сложно?

Comment: Вы хотите на JQuery или на php?

Comment: На PHP, раз вы сказали, что на JQuery небезопасно.

Comment: На php тоже можно будет прочекать все номера, правда, это будет менее удобно.

Comment: Так как я еще учусь, то хотелось бы на PHP, даже для самообразования.